# How to read a list of integers from an input line

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Is it possible to read a line with numerous numbers(integers) using Fortran?

lets say i have a file with only only line

```
1 2 3
```

the following program reads 3 integers in a line

```
program reading 
implicit none
integer:: dump1,dump2,dump3

read(21,*)  dump1,dump2,dump3

end
```

so dump1=1 dump2=3 dump3=3

If i have a file with only one line but with numerous integers like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...  10000
```

is ti possible the above program to work without defining 10000 variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*EDIT The first paragraph of this answer might seem rather strange as OP has modified the question.*

Your use of the term `string` initially confused me, and I suspect that it may have confused you too.  It's not incorrect to think of any characters in a file, or typed at a command-line as a string, but when all those characters are digits (interspersed with spaces) it is more useful to think of them as `integers`.  The Fortran run-time system will 
take care of translating a string of digit characters into an integer.

In that light I think your question might be better expressed as *How to read a list of integers from an input line ?*  Here's one way:

Define an array.  Here I define an array of fixed size:

```
integer, dimension(10**4) :: dump
```

(I often use expressions such as `10**4` to avoid having to count `0`s carefully).  This step, defining an array to capture all the values, seems to be the one you are missing.

To read those values from the terminal, at run-time, you might write

```
write(*,*) 'Enter ', 10**4, 'numbers now'
read(*,*) dump
```

and this will set `dump(1)` to the first number you type, `dump(2)` to the second, all the way to the `10**4`-th.  Needless to say, typing that number of numbers at the terminal is not recommended and a better approach would be to read them from a file. Which takes you back to your

```
read(21,*) dump
```

It wouldn't surprise me to find that your system imposes some limit on the length of a single line so you might have to be more sophisticated when trying to read as many as `10**4` integers, such as reading them in lines of 100 at a time, something like that.  That's easy

```
read(*,*) dump(1:100)
```

will read 100 integers into the first 100 elements of the array.  Write a loop to read 100 lines of 100 integers each.